# JUnit mocks, which tool should i use?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, jmock

I come from the PHP testing world and i'm starting testing in Java.

I've seen several tools to mock the SUT in JUnit, like Mockito, SevenMock, ClassMock, etc.

I really appreciate any recommendation of which one should i use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used Mockito quite a lot. http://mockito.org/ I have not used EasyMock so cant say much about it.

Using Mockito is straightforward but the classes that you intend to test should also be in a decoupled state which will make it easier to test. With mockito you are instantiating a particular class with mocks objects.

Say you got a class that you want to test, but want to mock one of its dependencies

```
final DepedencyToMockClass mockObject = mock(DepedencyToMockClass.class);
when(mockObject.getTestMethod()).thenReturn("Test");
```

Now this mockObject can now be injected when initializing your intended class.

```
final ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest(mockObject);
```

Mockito uses reflection to create these mock objects. However if you have a dependency and if it is declared final then mocking will fail.

Another useful method in Mockito is verify where you can verify certain operations in your mock objects. Have a peep at mockito. However there are limitations in mock objects, in some cases it will be hard to create mock objects perhaps external/third party code. I think it's good practise to attempt to instantiate real objects when injecting them for testing purposes, failing which Mockito helps.

Answer (score 7):

Mockito seems to be most often used

edit:

[Comparison between Mockito vs JMockit - why is Mockito voted better than JMockit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105592/comparison-between-mockito-vs-jmockit-why-is-mockito-voted-the-than-jmockit)

[EasyMock vs Mockito: design vs maintainability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864796/easymock-vs-mockito-design-vs-maintainability)

http://www.dahliabock.com/blog/2009/08/21/mocking-mockito-vs-easymock-example/

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) for a while. I personally like that the resulting code is easy to read, and you can easily differentiate between allowances and expectations:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        // allowances
        ignoring(parserState);
        allowing(factory).create(); will(returnValue(object));

        // expectations
        one(service).addSth(with(any(Integer.class)), with(sth));
    }});
```

Other powerful features are:

- Sequences: invocations in sequence.
- Argument matchers: hamcrest library
- States: constraint invocations when a condition is true.